# Meta: Why are there no custom class based views?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

It seems like such an obvious pattern that would be extremely useful, and help developers to conform to DRY. Eg, define a certain context that can be passed to each view. As far as I am aware, there is no way of doing this.

Comment: What do you mean? You have loads of types of Class based views. I'm sure you can do what you want. 
Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Can't the classes "extend" the required functionality? If not, what about the various decorator patterns?

Comment: @andrefsp For example, suppose there were a list of objects attached to the user that you needed to filter in a particular way for every template (this would probably be a job for a template tag, I'm just using it as an example), and you didn't want to define it in every view. Is there not a way to, for example, define a 'LoggedInView', with a custom base context, that you could then extend with other context definitions?

Answer (score 1):

All the generic class-based views can be extended and their methods overridden, as defined in the documentation. For example, if you wanted extra context variables defined in addition to the ones the view defines itself, just add them using the `get_context_data` method:

```
class CustomDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CustomDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            "foo": "bar",
            "baz": 999,
        })
        return context
```

Alternatively, you may want to define a certain mixin which would be included in every view as needed.